# List<Object> Or RealmList<RealmObject> on Realm Android

Tags: java, android, realm

I need a `list<Object>` using Realm. I tried `RealmList<RealmObject>` but it doesn't work because `RealmObject` is abstract.

Comment: can you explain these lines : " I try RealmList but it dosen't work because RealmObject it's abstract ".

Comment: I need List<Object> but Realm doesn't support it, so my question is : if there's any equivalent of   List<Object>  on Realm, even, I tried RealmList<RealmObject> but it's not working

Comment: I don't know Realm but RealmList<?> can solve your problem.

Comment: How about `RealmList<? extends RealmObject>` ?

Comment: Thank's, but it's working, because after I need to add object from model with index, it forced me to change ? to my object.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Christian from Realm here. You can only save objects that extend RealmObject inside a Realm. This is because Realm is not a schemaless database. We do require a schema and that schema is defined by your objects that extend RealmObject. We use RealmList because it abstracts away the communication with the underlying core database, but it implements the List interface.

This means that

```
public class Foo extends RealmObject {
  private List<Object> objects;  // not legal
  private RealmList<Object> objects;  // not legal 
  private RealmList<RealmObject> objects; // not legal
}

public class Foo extends RealmObject {
  private RealmList<Foo> objects; // legal
}

List<Foo> reference = foo.getObjects(); // Legal
```